# How to monitor a logs directory with OSSEC agent in windows

Tags: windows, monitoring

My problem is that I have some windows programs I want to monitor with the following structure in the logs filename:

`Program name%Y%m%d_%timestamp.log`

Where %timestamp is formed by the concatenation of hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds. I've already been reading the documentation about the OSSEC agent and performing some tests, and any of them where successful.

As the manual says at [the localfile section](http://ossec-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/syntax/head_ossec_config.localfile.html):

> Wildcards may be used on non-Windows systems

So I don't know how to monitor these logs folders. Can anyone help me, please?

Edit:

I don't want to monitor the file sizes or movements. I want to get the events contained in those logs and process them.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking at the log collector element rather than at the file integrity monitoring element which is covered by  in the documentation: https://ossec-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/syscheck/

Rather than looking at specific files, you could monitor the directory. You know the directory will increase in size and items will be deleted based on retention periods and automated jobs. Once you know these metrics, you'll be able to monitor for specific changes which may be suspicious or malicious.